# Button Capture get captured in android

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, augmented-reality, capture

i make an augmented reality project using capture image.
in my project i use button capture for capture the picture
but when i capture my button get captured too

this is the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class buttonCapture : MonoBehaviour {

public Texture iconCapture;
//private int filename;

void OnGUI(){
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (145, 530, 100, 45), iconCapture))
    {
        string filename = "image.jpg";
        Application.CaptureScreenshot(filename);

        if (Vuforia.QCARRuntimeUtilities.IsPlayMode()) {
            // if in PlayMode, the screenshot will be saved
            // to the project directory
            Debug.Log ("/storage/ " + filename);
        }
        else {
            // if running on Device, the screenshot will be saved
            // to the Application.persistentDataPath directory
            Debug.Log ("/storage/" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename);
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a bool you set to true while capturing the screenshot and set it false when done.
Use this bool to show and hide the button.

Comment: im very newbie in c#, if  get bool in my code where i put the true and the false? or i get in new script?and link it to my script button?